# Detect file type irrespective of file extension (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

Using NodeJS with multer, is it possible to detect the true file type of a file, regardless of its extension?

Scenario: you only allow certain file types to upload (`.jpeg` and `.docx`) The user takes a file, `pictures.rar`, renames it to `pictures.docx` and proceeds to upload the file. Your server expects only docs and image files and so blows up trying to read the docx.

Obviously this is user error, but is there a way to detect that and not proceed?

Comment: There are libraries that detect file types, an example would be ```file``` in unix and tools like [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a module to detect the type of file, but without having it on the server you will not be able to check it. So after uploading the file you test its type.

Module nodjs for file type : https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type

**EDIT 2022 : you can use [mime-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types) module**

Comment: By the way, does somebody know an option to test `xls` files?  `file-type` does not support checking of old `xls`, and I struggle to find an alternate library... Thanks in advance for the answer :)

Comment: I don't know, sorry. But if you want to read its content, you can do a try catch loop.

Comment: the problem with this package it uses ESM module, it looks like a lot change needs to be done at my project for a single package. And suppose if I do it, there is a chance my other modules go unsupported.

Comment: I found new module @senthilbalaji : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types

Comment: Thanks. Actually, mime types don't read the magic numbers to identify the file types. UPDATE: Seems like file-type has released a new version very recently that supports commonjs module https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type/v/13.0.0

Answer (score -1):

you can use file metadata npm package to get the file metadata and extract mime types from there 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-metadata